# Copy Data from Blob to SQL via Azure data factory

Tags: blob, dataflow, azure-data-factory

I have two sample files in blob as sample1.csv and sample2.csv as below

[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT0JM.png)

SQL table name sample2, with column Name,id,last name,amount

Created a ADF flow without schema, it results as below

[preview data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMlPO.png)

source settings are allow schema drift checked.
sink setting are auto mapping turned on. allow insert checked. table action none.

I have also tried setting a define schema in dataset, its result are same.

any help here?

my expected outcome would be data in sample1 will inserted null into the column "last name"

Comment: Hi Awo Ningan, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you said: "my expected outcome would be data in sample1 will inserted null into the column `last name`", you only need to add a [derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to you sample1.csv file.

You could follow my steps:

1. I create a sample1.csv file in Blob Storage and a sample2 table in my SQL database:
   [image]
   [image]
2. Using DerivedColumn to create new column `last name` with `null` value:

expression: `toString(null())`
[image]

3. Sink settings:
   [image]
4. Run the pipeline and check the data in table:
   [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thz Leon, this will only worked when source is from a single file, and this will failed if the source contains both files, as i have multiple files in the blob container.

Comment: @AwoNingan We can not copy multiple files with different schema to one Sink table. Source schema must has the same schema with sink.

Comment: @AwoNingan  Even in Data Flow, we only can using Join active  to to get  data/schema from two source datasets, then create new  DerivedColumn to alter the schema and data.

Comment: thz, that means i need to separate the source with according to schema difference.

Comment: @AwoNingan Yes, it is. If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @AwoNingan, do you have other questions? I would be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix schemas in the same source in the same data flow execution.

Schema Drift will handle changes to the schema on an execution-per-execution basis.

But if you are reading multiple different schemas from a folder, you will get non-deterministic results.

Instead, if you loop through those files in a pipeline ForEach one-by-one, data flow will be able to handle the evolving schema.

Comment: thanks, even thought i have fix the schema in the source, with 4 columns, it still doesn't work. it seems that it was mapping the data according to column orders, not columns names. i turned off column drift and auto mapping, same results

Comment: Clear out the schema in the source, do not use a set schema here

Comment: i did, it returns the same result, no matter if i have a fix schema in source or leave it empty. any idea?